# Unwanted tabs when opening a Firefox window

Tags: firefox, rss

Since Firefox 89 (maybe 89.0.2), whenever I start Firefox, or even a new window (Ctrl+N), it starts with a few annoying tabs open, always the same. They are not my previous session.

Most of them are the search shortcuts I set up with [wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/tools/Firefox-search-shortcut.aspx) (so you can type in Firefox search `enes dog` (english-español) and it will give you the translation `perro`).

One of the tabs is a website with a RSS feed I fiddled with long ago but never used (Could be here for another reason but I suspect strongly the RSS is why it shows up).

And a few others are websites I know, but have no idea why they show up at start.

When booting Firefox, my pinned websites are still here as they should, along with those unwanted tabs. My browser never did this before.

How can I stop those tabs from appearing when I start Firefox ?

Comment: Are those tabs [configured to open at start-up](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1271888)?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please don't forget to [accept it by clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) on the left side of the answer. A screenshot with a link to official Firefox documentation also makes the answer more comprehensive.

Comment: Can't accept my own answer until tomorrow. Not sure what documentation you refer to since I couldn't find any help of that kind, and I can't screenshot what helped me since it's not there anymore once you click it.

Answer (score 0):

I went into parameters, "homepage" (not sure how it's called in english, the menu with a house symbol), clicked the default configuration button, and it was fixed.